Getx: Transitioning to Detail Page Reloads Old Data and Stacks are Cleared After Phone Reboot
Hello  When I am on the detail page of getx, I need to click on a product to go to the detail page again. It transitions but first shows the old data. It updates the screen with data from the API. I solved it with Get.create. But this time, when I turn off the phone and turn it back on, the previous stacks are deleted. If anyone knows, I would appreciate it if they could help...
I tried using Get.create to navigate to the detail page and update the data from the API. I expected the detail page to transition smoothly without displaying old data. However, I noticed that the previous data was still shown briefly before updating with the new data.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
